# Did artifactory's "Allow content browsing" feature change or get disabled?

Tags: artifactory

We've been using Artifactory's "Allow content browsing" feature to serve up HTML documentation for quite a while, and it worked very well. Some time in the past few months, however, this features seems to have stopped working. Where before Artifactory would serve our HTML like a regular web server, it now just gives us the option to download the HTML files.

Did something change in Artifactory that prevents this from working? Is there some change that we need to make to our configuration to make it work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Artifactory 7.21.3 introduced an updated "[Native Content Browser](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.21.3)". We are working to allow HTML/HTM files rendering in the native browser, so it will come in the next releases.

Comment: Will this include executing JavaScript, or just rendering HTML?

Comment: Same as it was previously - the same behavior will be kept.

Comment: To recover previous behaviour we need to set: artifactory.redirect.native.browser.requests.to

Comment: What steps do we take to apply that setting? Is this in a file somewhere? Can I change it in the artifactory web interface?

Comment: Did this feature get added to JFrog? It doesn't appear to render HTML currently and the "Allow Content Browsing" option is grayed out in the settings for all of the repos. I raised a new stackoverflow question here on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76956017/jfrog-artifactory-native-browser-doesnt-render-html-files-forces-them-to-downl/77014327#77014327