# JFrog artifactory native browser doesn't render html files, forces them to download

Tags: artifactory

We have a JFrog cloud pro account and are trying to diagnose an issue with HTML files not rendering from the native browser, but instead downloading.

I've put several HTML files and a TXT file in `example-repo-local` and under the native browser the repo looks like this:

[image]

Clicking on any of the files causes the browser to download the file, not display it.

The links redirect to e.g. `https://<jfrog-host>/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=example-repo-local&path=index.html&isNativeBrowsing=true`, and looking at the browser network console it's clear that the `Content-Disposition` header is being set to `attachment`:

[image]

There seem to be discussions related to this issue (e.g. https://jfrog.atlassian.net//si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/RTFACT-26189/RTFACT-26189.html) that don't appear to have a resolution. Setting `artifactory.redirect.native.browser.requests.to.ui=false` on the repo doesn't appear to have any effect, whether it's set only on the repo or recursively.

Is serving static HTML from JFrog generic repo supported, and if so is there anything needed to enable it?

**Update after the first answer**: The `Allow Content Browsing` option is greyed out for the `example-repo-local`:

[image: grayed out check box]

Answer (score 1):

We can view HTML & JAVADOC files using Native Browser, you have to enable content browsing on the repository. You can follow this [wiki](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/advanced-settings) article for reference.

Be cautious while setting 'Allow Content Browsing', it may not be safe and therefore requires strict content moderation to prevent malicious users from uploading content that may compromise security.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `Allow Content Browsing` option is grayed out in our settings. Does it require an upgrade to our "Pro" account to use, or is there something else that needs configuring/enabling first?